# How do i check in composer who created the environment?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I want to check in composer who created the environment. In details only created at is visible but I am unable to find created by. Can anyone help me find that in GCP.

Comment: You can find that in the audit logs. They are kept 14 months by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an environment using Composer, the information about who created the environment is not explicitly displayed in the Cloud Console. However, you can gather this information through checking the **Cloud Console's Activity Logs**. Activity Logs provide a history of operations that were performed on resources in your GCP project.

- Open the Cloud Console and navigate to the **"Logging"** section from the left-hand navigation menu.
- In the **"Query Builder"** section, you can filter logs based on the **"resource.type"** (Composer), **"protoPayload.methodName"** (create), and **"timestamp."**
- Look for the entry related to the creation of your Composer environment. The logs should contain information about the user who performed the operation.

You can also check **IAM Audit Logs** to see who granted the necessary permissions for creating the Composer environment.

- Navigate to the **"IAM & Admin"** section in the Cloud Console and select **"Audit logs."**
- In the **"Filter"** panel, you can filter logs based on **"protoPayload.methodName"** (google.cloud.scheduler.job.AuditJob, google.cloud.scheduler.job.CreateJob), **"timestamp,"** and **"resource.type"** (composer.googleapis.com/Environment).
- Look for entries related to the creation of your Composer environment.

You can also use the **gcloud command-line tool** or the **GCP API** to retrieve information about the Composer environment, including its creation details.

Use the following command to get information about the Composer environment:

```
gcloud composer environments describe ENVIRONMENT_NAME --location LOCATION
```

Replace `ENVIRONMENT_NAME` with your Composer environment name and `LOCATION` with the GCP region where your Composer environment is located. Look for the `"creator"` field in the output.